# Click Once Deployment move published files, new published files update doesn't work

Tags: .net, clickonce, publish, move

net/vs experts :-)

i have some trouble with the click once deployment.

i developed an application for a customer, this customer wants to install the application from his network, and want to put the setup.exe on a netpath. now i try to test that scenario locally on my development environment.

i published the solution locally to c:\temp\myapp and moved this myapp folder to a virtual machine.
installing the applicaiton is no problem. but the installed application (on the virtual machine) doesn't recognize updates.

i published a newer version locally to c:\temp\myapp and moved the setup.exe, app.application and  replaced the existing. i also copied the new folder under Application Files (app_0_1_2_30) to the virtual machine.

But my app doesn't regcognize any update when i star it. Setting are fine: "Check updates at app's startup"...

what can i do? i there a solution on that ?

Comment: Did you increment the application version?

Comment: yes, the applications version incremented automatically. i checked that

Comment: ok. I suspect that application on the virtual machine searches for updates in the " c:\temp\myapp" folder (since this is the target for deployment). Do you have such directory with application on the virtual machine? I would suggest to deploy application to a folder with UNC format, for instance, \\mypc\app\\

Comment: i use the exact same directories c:\temp\myapp .. the only difference is the os win7 and xp (VM).

Comment: Well... Do not have any more ideas for now... What if you directly run the _app.application_ on the VM? Will clickonce load the latest version of your application?

Comment: app.application in the app root and in the "Application Files" "app_v1_x_x_x" works